# PHP create a copy command like phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new with PHP development and just wondering if theres a existing function on PHP than duplicate the `copy` command on phpmyadmin, i know that the query sequence is below, but this is like a long query/code since the table has alot of columns. i mean if phpmyadmin has this feature maybe its calling a build in function?

```
SELECT * FROM table where id = X
INSERT INTO table (XXX)VALUES(XXX)
Where the information is based from the SELECT query
```

Note: The id is primary and auto increment.

Here is the copy command on phpmyadmin

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i mean if phpmyadmin has this feature maybe its calling a build in function?

There is no built-in functionality in MySQL to duplicate a row other than an `INSERT` statement of the form: `INSERT INTO tableName ( columns-specification ) SELECT columns-specification FROM tableName WHERE primaryKeyColumns = primaryKeyValue`.

The problem is you need to know the names of the columns beforehand, you also need to exclude `auto_increment` columns, as well as primary-key columns, and know how to come up with "smart defaults" for non-`auto_increment` primary key columns, especially composite keys. You'll also need to consider if any triggers should be executed too - and how to handle any constraints and indexes that may be designed to prevent duplicate values that a "copy" operation might introduce.

You can still do it in PHP, or even pure-MySQL (inside a sproc, using Dynamic SQL) but you'll need to query `information_schema` to get metadata about your database - which may be more trouble than it's worth.